# Google Play Game services ANE version 5089000

Tags: actionscript-3, air, google-play-games, air-native-extension, ane

I have been using my own ANE for my android games and it works great.
It has AdMob, Leaderboards and Achievements functionality. I used Google Play Game services version **4242000**, which was the latest version when I first started building it.

Now there's a new version of Google Play Game services: **5089000**

I wanted to migrate to this new version and implement new features. However, the ANE doesn't work with it. All I did was I replaced the `google-play-services.jar` with the newer one (i.e. I replaced version **4242000** with **5089000**). The ANE compiles successfully but when testing, the `ExtensionContext.createExtensionContext()` always returns **NULL**!!! And as I said, when compiled with the older `google-play-services.jar` (which is version **4242000**), it works perfectly.

I did a test android project in Eclipse, with the newer `google-play-services.jar` (version **5089000**), and all functionality worked. That means that the `.jar` file is not the problem.

I'm using the latest `Adobe AIR 15` to build the `swc` part of the ANE.

Has anyone experienced anything similar? Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like

```
abd logcat
```

can answer why context cannot be created.